Is there any browser wallet extension that supports Bitcoin Testnet similar to MetaMask for Ethereum Testnet?
I'm looking for a browser extension that works as a Bitcoin wallet and supports Bitcoin Testnet, similar to how MetaMask works for Ethereum and its testnets (like Goerli or Sepolia). Does such an extension exist for Bitcoin, or are there alternative ways to interact with the Bitcoin Testnet through a browser?

Why does the wallet you use need to be a browser extension to solve your problem? How would that help you solve the actual problem you are facing? What are you actually trying to achieve? I’m not aware of any major/well-developed browser wallets and given that browsers are famously insecure environments, I’d be surprised to learn one exists.
